# Reduce timeout in Visual Studio nuget package manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to reduce the timeout in the **Manage NuGet Packages** visual studio extension? I've been waiting for it to do something for over 10 minutes now and am getting bored of waiting. I've been getting a lot of timeouts recently and ideally would like to know how to diagnose/fix those, but would settle for a shorter timeout so I don't waste so much time twiddling my thumbs waiting for it to decide it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get in touch with [the developers](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) and suggest them to include in the plugin a way to set a custom timeout for some actions. Being an open-source project I'm sure they will have ears for you :) If that doesn't work... you can grab the source code and make the improvements yourself.